# Upload Photo and tag friends Facebook SDK C#

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I can upload the photo now and also I can tag a place in the same post. But when I tag some friends I got `OAuthException #100 tags parameter must be non-empty`.
What I want is to upload the photo on the timeline with friends tagging on the post not on the photo.

I did a research for a couple of week but no answer for this. My algorithm is first to upload the photo and then post with the tags, but I have no idea about the API.

Here is my code:

```
var Posting = "/me/photos";
WriteableBitmap wrbitIma = new WriteableBitmap(bitMapImage);
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
Extensions.SaveJpeg(wrbitIma, ms, bitMapImage.PixelWidth, bitMapImage.PixelHeight, 0, 100);

PostParam = new
{
    message = TxtBox.Text,
    place = FacebookHelper.PlaceID,
    tags = FacebookHelper.array_ofSelFriendsID,
    picture = new FacebookMediaObject { ContentType = "image/jpeg", FileName = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("ddmmyyyyhhmmss") + "-photo.jpeg" }.SetValue(ms.ToArray()),
    privacy = new { value = stringPrivacy() }
};

_cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
var uploadProgress = new Progress<FacebookUploadProgressChangedEventArgs>();
uploadProgress.ProgressChanged += (o, args) => UploadingProgressBar.Value = args.ProgressPercentage;

dynamic fbPostTaskResult = await facebookClient.PostTaskAsync(Posting, PostParam, null, _cts.Token, uploadProgress);
```

Plus, why do I see `UploadProgress` is always full at 100% ?

Comment: The UploadProgress doesnt work for WP7/WP8 currently as WP7 doesn't have AllowWriteStreamBuffering in HttpWebRequest, so everything is written in memory and then written to the request (which we have no control off), thus the progress getting 100% is from writing to the memory. We are looking into supporting this via reflection. So it is a noop for WP7 only.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of that might be causing this is that, if those certain friends who don't tag properly have their settings geared not to allow tags. In that case there's nothing you can do about that, it's all on them.

Comment: But I can do the text post with tags and place without problem. The problem happens only with the photo and the tags.
text + tags = ok,
text + tags + place = ok,
photo + place = ok,
photo + text = ok,
photo + tags = error occurs